# Does OpenCV initialize weights matrix with zeros, cv::ml::ANN_MLP

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, opencv3.3

Its mentioned on OpenCV docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/dce/classcv_1_1ml_1_1ANN__MLP.html)

> Artificial Neural Networks - Multi-Layer Perceptrons.
>
> Unlike many other models in ML that are constructed and trained at
>   once, in the MLP model these steps are separated. First, a network
>   with the specified topology is created using the non-default
>   constructor or the method ANN_MLP::create. **All the weights are set
>   to zeros.** Then, the network is trained using a set of input and
>   output vectors. The training procedure can be repeated more than once,
>   that is, the weights can be adjusted based on the new training data.

And also it is mentioned:

> UPDATE_WEIGHTS
>
> Update the network weights, rather than compute them from scratch.
>   **In the latter case the weights are initialized using the Nguyen-Widrow algorithm**.

So I wanted to know what happens exactly with the weight initialization when I go onto train a model. Answers related to OpenCV 3.3.1 are also appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any reason to doubt documentation? OpenCV is open source library, so you can see what is beneath by yourself [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/ann_mlp.cpp)

```
ANN_MLPImpl()
{
    clear();
    setActivationFunction( SIGMOID_SYM, 0, 0);
    setLayerSizes(Mat());
    setTrainMethod(ANN_MLP::RPROP, 0.1, FLT_EPSILON);
}
```

When you call `train` `init_weights()` may be called

```
bool train( const Ptr<TrainData>& trainData, int flags )
{
    // Some code
    // ... and link weights
    if( !(flags & UPDATE_WEIGHTS) )
        init_weights();
    // Even more code
```

And here is `init_weights()`

```
void init_weights()
{
    //... More code
        // initialize weights using Nguyen-Widrow algorithm
        for( j = 0; j < n2; j++ )
        {
            double s = 0;
           // .. more initialization code
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first part of the documentation I mentioend be updated then ... its kind of confusing